# How to extract specific fields from CSV file with data using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to extract the specific fields with data from the CSV file, but when I do run the following script, I do get only the fields without data on it.

Tried PowerShell script and got the file, but it's empty.

```
$folderPath = 'D:\Data\Orignal\'
$folderPathDest = 'D:\Data\New\'
$desiredColumns = 'ID','TC', 'POINTS_AT','POINTS_DESC','SURVEYSENT'

Get-ChildItem $folderPath -Name | ForEach-Object { 
    $filePath = $folderPath + $_
    $filePathdest = $folderPathDest + $_

    Import-Csv $filePath |
        Select $desiredColumns |
        Export-Csv -Path $filePathDest -NoTypeInformation
}
```

I do expect that data should be exported as well with fields!

Here is an example data from where I am trying to extract fields. It's sample file, I have big dump.

```
ID;TC;POINTS_AT;POINTS_DESC;SURVEYSENT;STATUSCHECK;MEM_REQ;EXPIRY_DAT
1;true;5;SUBS;true;08.08.2018;true;20.12.2020
2;true;3;SUBS;true;08.08.2018;true;20.12.2020
3;false;2;SUBS;true;08.08.2018;false;20.12.2020
4;true;5;UNSUBS;true;08.08.2018;false;20.12.2020
5;true;1;UNSUBS;true;08.08.2018;true;20.12.2020
6;false;1;UNSUBS;true;08.08.2018;true;20.12.2020
```

Comment: Please show sample input. The most likely reason for getting empty fields in the output file is that your input files don't have the fields you think they do.

Comment: As an aside, as a future consideration: In PowerShell _Core_ `$_` would stringify to the _full path_, and even in Windows PowerShell that could happen, depending on the specifics of the `Get-ChidItem` command; better to use `$_.Name` for clarity and robustness.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers check i did updated

Comment: `Import-Csv $filePath` -> `Import-Csv $filePath -Delimiter ';'`

Comment: Default delimiter for the `*-Csv` cmdlets is the comma, not the semicolon.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers can you reproduce the above script with changes you suggest, so i can be more clear ?

Comment: This is a trivial change. If you're unable to fit it into your existing code: please go find a PowerShell tutorial right now.

Comment: i think i am able to make it my self using your suggestion, let me test with big dump file....

Comment: Like @AnsgarWiechers wrote add the delimiter. It will look like this `Import-Csv $filePath -Delimiter ';'| Select $desiredColumns | Export-Csv -Path $filePathDest -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `;` as delimiter when calling `Import-Csv`. The default delimiter is `,` ,  so the cmdlet won't be able to split the different columns. Based on that, `Select-Object` won't find the given properties, and will return objects with empty properties.

[Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6#parameters):

> Delimiter
>
> Specifies the delimiter that separates the property values in the CSV file. The default is a comma (,).
>
> Enter a character, such as a colon (:). To specify a semicolon (;) enclose it in single quotation marks.