# Can the Excel PowerPivot data model process string lengths of >32,767 characters in a field?

Tags: excel, csv, powerpivot

I'm working with a csv file that contains 1 field (out of 10 total fields) with very large strings (50,000+ characters). The other 9 fields contain strings of normal length (<100).

I imported this file into the PowerPivot data model and then copied the data directly from the table view in PowerPivot into Notepad++.

All of the strings in Notepad++ are 32,767 characters, which suggests that PowerPivot has the same limitations as standard Excel in this respect.

Is there something I can do in PowerPivot to enable a field to hold more than 32,767 characters, or am I going to have to find another solution?

Fyi, the objective is to extract this long string (which is a base64-encoded jpeg) from the csv and save it as a separate text file (which would then be converted back to a jpeg with PowerShell...a script I've already developed).

The remainder of the data in the original csv would be saved as a table and combined with some other data from a few other sources to create one table to upload into our Salsify PIM.

I've asked the provider of this csv if it's possible to export the very long strings as individual text files with names that I could relate back to the original dataset (which would solve my problem instantly), but there is resistance. They are insisting on putting everything in one csv.

Note that I do have some experience in Python (and of course PowerShell) and am open to learning tools like PowerAutomate or any other tool that you'd recommend for something like this.

edit: Note that the jpeg files I'm working with range in size from 10KB all the way up to ~16MB, so the base64 string can get very long (in the range of 3.5M characters).

Comment: Look at ADO. I hope Python supports it.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to [split an image into multiple rows](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2019/05/19/storing-large-images-in-power-bi-datasets/) of 30,000 characters and concatenation it back together in DAX. Images up to about 2.1MB should be supported this way.

Comment: Thanks for the info Greg!

I should have specified that many of these images are 3+MB...some are 16MB.

So in some cases I'd be working with over a 100 individual 30K character-chunks per image in PowerQuery, which may be technically feasible...but sounds a bit cumbersome (the author mentioned that processing the 2.1MB was not that efficient...so 16MB might put it over the edge).

I need to figure out how to strip the base64 field out of the csv and create separate txt files for each base64 image before the csv gets consumed by PQ.

I imagine PS could do this...just don't know how yet.

Comment: I'll start here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56543411/how-to-extract-specific-fields-from-csv-file-with-data-using-powershell

Comment: Sounds like you may need to manually edit the images and size the dimensions down or turn down the quality (turn up the compression) to get them under 2.1MB or this approach won’t work.